# convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary of data passed from another viewController, and when I tried to fetch the id from the dictionary it gives me conversion error!

```
var comments = [JSON]()

@IBAction func AddCommentBTN(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let commentTXT = CommentTXTField.text
    let name =   self.accountDetails["name"]
    let email =  self.accountDetails["email"]
    let articleId = self.comments["id"].string! ----> error is here 
    API.AddComment(articleId: "", name: name!, email: email!, message: commentTXT!) { (error: Error?, success: Bool) in
        if success {
            self.CommentTableView.reloadData()
            print("Registerd Successfuly")
        } else {
            print("Faile To Comment")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: “Code snippets“ are only for JavaScript/HTML/CSS.

Comment: What type is `JSON`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `self.comments` is an array of `JSON` object. So before getting value from the JSON you need to get the object first from the array. Before getting the `0` index value make sure the array contains value.

Seems like you are using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse the value. So by using `.intValue` you can get the `Int` value. `.intValue` will return a Int type value. If the key not present there then this will return you the 0 value. `.intValue` not an `Optional` type.

Try this

```
let articleId = self.comments[0]["id"].intValue
```

instead of

```
let articleId = self.comments["id"].string!
```

Answer (score -1):

You are converting a `String` to Int which is not as straightforward as you may think. The `String` can contain characters that is not a number like "Forest". To convert a `String` to `Int` you can use:

```
if let myInt = Int(self.comments["id"]) {
    let articleId = myInt
}
```

It will check if the string is a correct Int and return an Optional value. You can also use a fallback to define a default value if the `String` is not correct `Int`

```
let myInt = Int(self.comments["id"]) ?? 0
```

That means “attempt to convert `self.comments["id"]` to an integer, but if the conversion failed because it contained something invalid then use 0 instead.”

Comment: Could you please share the code where you define the JSON object ?

Answer (score -1):

The values of a json are optional and might be on any allowed type. A way parsing this save would be getting the value for "id", which will be an optional, and try to convert this optional to an Int. The Int itself is optional as well. (Short, it might be there or not)

```
guard let value = self.comments["id"], let articleId = Int64(value) else {
 // Not valid
 return
 }
 print(articleId)
```

A better way would be parsing your json data to an object in the first place. Your controller would not need to deal with the parsing of optional data, but instead just get the right data from the object.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.